# Copying x-value by value returned by a function

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I stumbled upon a code similar to this while debugging a crash due to de-referencing a dangling piece of memory.

```
template<typename RaiiObject, typename HandleType>
const HandleType& ExtractHandle(const RaiiObject &value){

    const HandleType* val = value.get(); // get underlying managed object
    return static_cast<const HandleType&>(*val);
}
```

On the caller side the code looked like this:

```
const auto &x = ExtractHandle(GetAHandle());
```

This is a definitely a problem because the reference to the underlying object that we will be getting from `ExtractHandle` will be dangling since the Raii object managing it would have expired.

Now the dev fixing this issue replaced the capture by reference to capture by value.

```
auto x = ExtractHandle(GetAHandle());
```

His claim is that since we are making a copy, we are safe **since the x-value returned by GetAHandle will not die till the copy constructor for Handle is invoked**. Is this assumption correct? Is it well defined by standard that the above proposed fix is not UB?

Note: While the correctness and utility of this design can definitely be questioned, the point is more around whether copying by value guarantees a well defined behavior

Comment: he is correct, but the code is still garbage. make ExtractHandle return a copy and be done with it. Also, why casting away const? evil!

Comment: Unrelated, but can't you say `return *val;` instead of `return static_cast<HandleType&>(*val);`?

Comment: The bigger problem here is that `RaiiObject::get()` may return a copy. So `val` would be a pointer to an rvalue. I don't know how long rvalues are kept around, but I would assume the copy wouldn't even survive till the return statement. At the very latest it would be destroyed when the function terminates.

So if  `RaiiObject::get()` returns a copy `ExtractHandle()` is guaranteed to return an invalid reference.

Comment: This function returns an lvalue, not an xvalue

Comment: The suggested fix takes a copy of the underlying object  - this might not be desirable behaviour , there would be reasons why the object was managed like this in the first place.  It's possible that there will be other problems depending on how the copy semantics are defined for the  managed object. (For example if it is a handle being managed, the handle might be freed leaving you with a dangling handle still).  You need to do a more in-depth code review than just doing this quick fix.

Comment: @M.M Agreed. That is why I have a footnote there. I am almost stomping to change the design of ExtractHandle. Extracting the underlying handle from a RAII is anyways a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is fine.**

The temporary created by `GetAHandle()` will only be destroyed at the end of that statement, so as long as your copy constructor doesn't retain any handles to the innards of that object, you're fine.

> `(N3337) [class.temporary]/3:` [...] Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step
>   in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. [...]

Answer (score 2):

Do it properly. Return a copy and be done with it:

```
template<typename RaiiObject, typename HandleType>
HandleType ExtractHandle(const RaiiObject &value){

    return *value.get(); // get underlying managed object
}
```

In which case, either of these will be valid:

```
const auto &x = ExtractHandle(GetAHandle()); 
auto x = ExtractHandle(GetAHandle());
```

because there is a special rule that keeps a temporary alive bound to a const reference alive for the lifetime of the reference.

Comment: And if `RaiiObject` is moveable, this is just as efficient.

Comment: Even if it isn't, RVO will make it costless